# Move swap partition

Tags: partitioning, debian, swap

How can I move swap (sda5) partition in my Debian 7 from main SSD disk to second HDD?

lsblk output

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  93.2G  0 part /home
├─sdb6   8:22   0  93.1G  0 part /tmp
└─sdb7   8:23   0 745.2G  0 part /var
sda      8:0    0  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    28G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this "properly" is a bit tricky because it entails shrinking /var and creating a new partition, then formatting it as swap, then mounting it (ie modifying /etc/fstab).  You would then presumably reclaim the space on /dev/sda5 by blowing away sda2 and sda5, enlarging sda1 and resizing the root filesystem.

An easier alternative which won't perform quite as well would be to make a swapfile in /var and mount that over a loopback device, which means you don't need to shrink /var.  Here is a [howto](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04) to create a swap file for Ubuntu - identical in debian.  Summarizing -

(as root) -

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.file bs=4096 count=102400   (makes a swap file, adjust count to make it bigger)
mkswap /var/swap.file   (to format the swapfile)
add "/var/swapfile   none swap sw 0 0" to /etc/fstab and remove the old entry
swapoff -a; swapon -a     to make swap take affect
```

To reclaim space on /dev/sda
BACK UP YOUR SYSTEM.  THIS IS DANGEROUS.

Boot from a boot disk

```
fdisk /dev/sda
delete sda2 and sda5
recreate sda1 with identical start, boot flag and filetype.  Change the end size.  (You may be able to use an alternative program to do this)
reboot
resize2fs /dev/sda1   (may be resize4fs depending on OS)
```

Done.

Comment: /tmp, which surely doesn't need 93GB, could be resized too. It's more secure since /tmp doesn't contain useful data but /var does.

Comment: By the way, may I write to /etc/fstab "/var/swapfile" or "/var/swap.file"because we created file named "/var/swap.file" (with dot) ?

Comment: Filename in /etc/fstab should be the same as the actual filename, so if the file you created is /var/swap.file then fstab should have swap.file.  (The name is aribtrary).

Comment: I got a little problem when I try to edit fstab I have got in it two swaps may I delete both ? [there is my fstab file](http://dl.ps-bred02.eu/get/fstab)

Comment: Yes, you can delete them (but you might be better off just commenting them out with a # at the beginning of the line).  Also, it occurs to me you are moving swap from a high speed disk to a low speed one.  This can have hard performance implications, and you may want to play arround with vm.swappiness (google or search it in SU) to avoid using swap.